# Need to change csv header from camel case to snake case in dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I am working on a pipeline to dynamically dump all columns from the salesforce object to the S3 bucket.
I get all columns for a salesforce object using describe object API. I store all columns into a variable and then create a big SOQL query out of it and submit a bulk query job v2.

Now, this is the main problem. The Column name I am getting from the salesforce connector is in camelCase

```
 [{
    "Id": 123, 
     "FirstName": "Manual", 
     "MasterRecordId__c" :"abc"
    },
    {   
    "Id": 456, 
     "FirstName": "John", 
     "MasterRecordId__c" :"def"
 }]
```

But I want column names to be in snake case

```
[{ 
   "Id": 123, 
   "first_name": "Manual", 
   "master_record_id__c":"abc"
  },
  {   
   "Id": 456, 
   "first_name": "john", 
   "master_record_id__c":"def"
 }]
```

I understand mulesoft has an **underscore** function to do the same thing, but I am not able to apply any function at "key" level.

Any lead would be really helpful. Please let me know for any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use `mapObject` along with the `underscore` function

```js
%dw 2.0
import underscore from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
---
payload map ((item) -> 
    item mapObject ((value, key) -> {
        (underscore(key)): value       
    })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want Id field to remain as it is, give a try like below:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json  
---
payload map ($ mapObject ((value, key, index) -> if (capitalize(key as String) == key as String)
    {
      (key): value
    }
  else
    {
      (underscore(key)): value
    }))
```